# how to create jquery ui date picker current month and date and year show only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

how to create jquery ui date picker current month and date and year show only

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <label for="email">Check Date:</label><br />
        <input id="datepicker" class="input" name="date" type="text" value=""  required/><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tell me how to disable all and enable only current date time and year

Comment: what do you mean by "current month and date and year show only"?

Comment: why then be able to pick if you disable the ability to change the date and year, and in your sample you have also disabled month.

Comment: I mean that i show this in form, but I want user can't change date or month or year only in calender current date show and other are disable just check this code you will understand that what I want to say

Comment: so you just want to show the date in calendar but not let the user change it?

Comment: yes sir now please help me how to do it what changes done in my code

Comment: Are you looking for a read only datepicker?

Comment: no sir I want only current time datepicker only he/she select them but other dates are should be disabled

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

but my suggestion if you don't want user to change it then instead of datepicker just have div and show the current date.

Comment: do you really need date picker for this requirements? You can do this without date picker eaisly.